# How can I access a Ubuntu FUSE mount in Windows via WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, sshfs, fuse

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 in Windows 11 via WSL 2.0.4. Within Ubuntu, I've used `sshfs` to mount a remote directory to `/media/remote1`. My local Ubuntu user owns the mount point.

I want to access that mounted folder in Windows via the WSL network share. I can access the `media` folder in Windows Explorer (`\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\media`), but trying to access the mount folder results in pop-up an error saying *"\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\media\mount1 is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource..."*

The sshfs mounted folder is accessible from within Ubuntu.

I've also tried mounting it using a few variations of `sshfs -o allow_other,default_permissions,ro` but no luck.

What is needed to allow Windows to access a FUSE-mounted drive via the WSL network share?